# Application is using another way of communication?

Tags: android, api, reverse-engineering, burp

I'm trying to spy requests of certain android application using Burp which worked for me before, but when I do, Burp only logs a few http/s request and WS logs, but none related to the request that the app is doing. I was wondering if there's  any other way an app can communicate with the server.

Answer (score 0):

Well in the android pentesting, the android developers put ssl pinning in place, so maybe that's why you are not able to see other requests.
But first make sure you have the prior permission to pentest and break ssl pinning of any app.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33362730)